# How to post form on successful paypal payment?

Tags: jquery, forms, paypal, http-post, form-post

I have a form on my HTML page containing paypal button and paypal credit card button.
This is a simple HTML, JS site, not a webstore. How can I post the form programatically after successful payment? My **onApprove** part is not working below.
**Only paypal sandbox account is set at the moment.*

```
paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                color: 'black',
                shape: 'rect',
                label: 'paypal',
                height: 45
            },
            createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: total
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },
            onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
                return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                    // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                    $('#orderForm').submit();
                });
            }
            //fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a client-side `actions.order.capture()`, you should NOT post a form nor write to a database, or anything of this nature. Client-side integrations are not for that use case. If you need to send or store data on a server as part of a PayPal transaction, you ought to use a server-side integration:

---

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

If you need to transmit data to the server, add a request body to the `fetch`; don't use a form post.